# What's wrong with this factory dependencies issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

I'm working with AngularJS.
I'd like to get a controller using a first factory which using another one.

It could be schematize like that:

```
MyCtrl -> Factory1 -> Factory2
```

So I tried to do in 3 different files (loaded in the following order):

*Factory2.js*

```
app.factory('Factory2', function () { ... })
```

*Factory1.js*

```
app.factory('Factory1',['Factory2', function (Factory2) { ... })
```

*controller.js*

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', 'Factory1', function ($scope, Factory1) { ... })
```

And in my HTML I have:

```
<script src="services/factory2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="services/factory1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it doesn't work and I've got this error  `Unknown provider: Factory2Provider <- Factory2 <- Factory1`

What's wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Comment: create a plnkr to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor your codes and use modules, in this way you will not need to use $inject

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['factories', 'mymodule']);

angular.module('factories', [])
    .factory('Factory2', function () { })
    .factory('Factory1', ['Factory2', function (Factory2) {
         return myCustomFunction = function () {
             alert('todo');
         }
    }]);

angular.module('mymodule', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Factory1', function ($scope, Factory1) {
    $scope.text = "testing";
}])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kL78rdr3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use explicit injection with **$inject**? It is a better approach, because it gives you more control over the dependencies. For example:

userController.js

```
function userController (model, routeParams, searchService) {
    //implementation
}
userController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'searchService'];
app.controller("userController", userController);
```

searchService.js

```
var searchService = function (http, log) {
    //implementation
}
searchService.$inject = ["$http", "$log"];
app.factory("searchService", searchService);
```

---

This post may be useful: [Explicit Dependency Injection](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/explicit-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll try it like that. I just start angular and didn't know `$inject`

Comment: Read this post, it can throw light on the matter: [Explicit Dependency Injection](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/explicit-dependency-injection)

Comment: Ok, I read it. Btw, in your controller example and the article the function is named and there's no variable. But forthe service you use a named variable with unnamed function. Is-it intentional?

Comment: Explicit dependency isn't a necessity, just as long as you using that array injection

Comment: Explicit dependency injection is a good practice when you code will be **uglyfied**, and it also allows you aliases the dependencies, see for example that we can aliases `$scope` as `model` or `vm` (there are other ways to do same), and besides the code (to me) is more legible.